# Hosting C# "Service Library" in Azure

Tags: c#, wcf, azure

I have a C# WCF Service Library that's running properly locally. A client running locally was able to see the service and consume it.
However, when I tried hosting the service in a WebRole and deploying it on Azure, the client was never able to connect to it successfully the same way it did locally! The way I did it was as follows:

```
// The WCF Service library is in namespace: Root.Library    
Uri url = new Uri("http://xxx.cloudapp.net:8099/DealerService"); // tried also without "DealerService" but still didn't work
ServiceHost host = new ServiceHost(typeof(Root.Library.DealerService), url));
host.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(Root.Library.IDealerService), new WSHttpBinding(), "DealerService");

ServiceMetadataBehavior dealerMetaBehavior = new ServiceMetadataBehavior();
dealerMetaBehavior.HttpGetEnabled = true;
host.Description.Behaviors.Add(dealerMetaBehavior);

host.Open();
```

And inside Root.Library, the app.config:

```
<service name="Root.Library.DealerService">
    <endpoint address="" binding="wsHttpBinding" name="dealer" contract="Root.Library.IDealerService">
      <identity>
        <dns value="localhost" />
      </identity>
    </endpoint>
    <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" name="mex" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
    <host>
      <baseAddresses>
        <add baseAddress="http://xxx.cloudapp.net:8099/" />
      </baseAddresses>
    </host>
  </service>
```

I also added an Endpoint to the WebRole config (Type:Input, Protocol:http, PublicPort:8099)

Can someone tell me what the problem might be??? this is really confusing me!

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You should just be able to change the port based on the csdef file

```
<Endpoints>
  <InputEndpoint name="Endpoint1" protocol="http" port="8888" />
</Endpoints>
```

Saqib Ullah has a post on geekswithblogs that shows more information: http://geekswithblogs.net/technetbytes/archive/2011/04/25/145035.aspx

Comment: The link is (effectively) broken. It redirects to *[Geekswithblogs.net, the End of an Era](http://julian.farm/geekswithblogs/?url=/mtreadwell/archive/2004/06/06/6123.aspx)*.